# SSDT unit testing of scripts

Tags: unit-testing, t-sql, sql-server-data-tools

Our DB solution has scripts that are not part of the schema (tables, procedures, etc.)
Generally, these scripts mostly select (part of BI)
What is the correct approach unit test these scripts?

I cannot find a way to add to the test designer the "include" or :/r.

The expectation is to call a script and receive a dataset that can be verified with test conditions

Comment: It's hard to answer due to the lack info given. What exact scripts? Can you give an example? How do you want to call them? It is probably needed to be done with the Post-script